# MySQL queries: two SELECT or one with LEFT Join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Is there any difference between two `SELECTs` from database or single `SELECT with LEFT Join`?

I am limited by number of queries per hour and I am developing my own application.

`"SELECT * FROM table"` represents one query?

`"SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN another_table ON table.column=another_table.column2'"` represents one query too?

Are `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` considered query?

Thanks a lot. If my post is not ok, I can delete.

Comment: Making joins should not decrease your query limit by number of joins you are making. Also - technically yes, as far as I know mysql performs multiple selects on joins.

Comment: You should ask your service provider. For sure each SELECT is counted as one query (so one SELECT with 10 JOIN will be **counted** as one query) but for other commands we can't say (what if you do 10.000 INSERT and 1 SELECT?)

Comment: Do you want to join simply just to reduce the number of SELECTs or do the joins make technical and logical sense?

Comment: IMPORTANT You should ask your hosting provider what type of query are they limiting. For example, we are limiting only SELECT queries. So, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE could not be a problem.

Comment: @Argeman I am creating my own application. I want to make as less queries as possible.

Comment: @NETCreator thanks, you're right. They are only limit my SELECT queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have limited number of queries, than `LEFT JOIN` is better, since it's only one query (one connection to database). And yes, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` is queries too. But You can insert multiple entries with single query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, joining tables is one query. Splitting that query and executing separately will take more time.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` is better, because it is  only one query and need only one connection to database.

`SELECT`,`UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` are all queries

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always better to use less query than more, so in your case better to use join than run 2 queries.

However you should add indexes to `table.column` and `another_table.column2` to make sure it won't affect your performance.

Of course all queries, also `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` are considered as queries, not only `SELECT`